# "API permission failed" for fetching DataExtension_Row from Marketing Cloud using FuelSDK-python

Tags: python-3.x, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I'm trying to fetch one Data Extension from Marketing Cloud. I'm using FuelSDK for python. I can list a collection of DataExtensions in an account but cannot fetch DataExtension_Row for one specific Data Extension. It always says "API permission failed".

Can someone please guide me whats wrong. I'm following the official documentation and the code looks fine. I also have all of the permissions.

```
def retrieve_job_view():
    myClient = ET_Client(True, False,
                         {
                             'clientid': 'xxxxx',
                             'clientsecret': 'xxxxx',
                             'useOAuth2Authentication': 'True',
                             'authenticationurl': 'https://xxxxx.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/',
                             'baseapiurl': 'https://xxxxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/',
                             'soapendpoint': 'https://xxxxx.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx',
                             'applicationType': 'server',
                             'account_id': 'xxxxx'
                         })

    row = ET_DataExtension_Row()
    row.auth_stub = myClient
    # row.CustomerKey = '20210105_xyz'
    row.Name = ['xyz']
    row.props = ['JobID', 'EventDate', 'CreatedDate']
    getResponse = row.get()
    print('Retrieve Status: ' + str(getResponse.status))
    print('Code: ' + str(getResponse.code))
    print('Message: ' + str(getResponse.message))
    print('MoreResults: ' + str(getResponse.more_results))
    print('RequestID: ' + str(getResponse.request_id))
    print('Results Length: ' + str(len(getResponse.results)))
    print('Results: ' + str(getResponse.results))
```

**This is the response:
**

```
Code: 200
Message: Error: API Permission Failed.
MoreResults: False
RequestID: dc01a58f-0088-48ac-b079-3bb9deccdf33
Results Length: 0
Results: []
```

[permissions are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tYRE.png)

[permissions are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lbIL.png)